# MySQL group by similar neighboring values

Tags: mysql

I want to group values together, but only if they are neighboring

For example, my table looks like this:

```
Date                 is_valid
2015-03-01            1
2015-03-02            1
2015-03-03            0
2015-03-04            0
2015-03-05            1
2015-03-06            1
2015-03-07            0
2015-03-08            0
```

I would like to get the ranges of 0's and 1's, lets say

`SELECT MIN(date) AS start, MAX(date) AS end, is_valid FROM tablename GROUP BY ????`

Where the expected result would be something like this:

```
start        end           is_valid
2015-03-01    2015-03-02    1
2015-03-03    2015-03-04    0
2015-03-05    2015-03-06    1
2015-03-07    2015-03-08    0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any id field in your table?

Comment: Yes, there's an auto-increment ID field

Comment: I can give you an idea on how to split your date column. Let me to try how I can get it in exact format you want. Try modifying my following query to arrive at you solution.

Comment: `select  
case 
when MOD(id, 2) = 1 then date1  end as startdate, 
case  
when MOD(id, 2) = 0 then date1 end as enddate, 
is_valid from your_table`   (After this confused about group by)